# Set 3 level of column names in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-level

I'm trying to have a frame with the following structure

```
              h/a                            totales

        sub1             sub2          sub1           sub2
   a  b ...   f         g ....m    a  b ...   f         g ....m
```

That being, 2 labels for the first layer, again 2 labels for the second one, and then a subset of column names where sub1 and sub2 doesn't have the same column names.

In order to do so I did the following:

```
columnas=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['h/a','totals'],['means','percentages'],
[('means','a'),('means','b'),....('percentage','g'),....],
names=['data level 1','data level 2','data level 3']])

data=[data,pata,......]
newframe=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columnas)
```

What I get is this error:

```
>ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 21), indices imply (84, 21)
```

How can I fix this to have a multi leveled frame by column names?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) from list comprehensions:

```
L1 = list('abc')
L2 = list('ghi')

tups = ([('h/a','means', x) for x in L1] + 
       [('h/a','percentage', x) for x in L2] + 
       [('totals','means', x) for x in L1] + 
       [('totals','percentage', x) for x in L2])

columnas=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups, names=['data level 1','data level 2','data level 3'])
print (columnas)
MultiIndex(levels=[['h/a', 'totals'], 
                   ['means', 'percentage'], 
                   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
                   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
           names=['data level 1', 'data level 2', 'data level 3'])

#some random data
np.random.seed(785)
data = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 12))
print (data)
[[8 0 4 1 2 5 4 1 4 1 1 8]
 [1 5 0 7 4 8 4 1 3 8 0 2]
 [5 9 4 9 4 6 3 7 0 5 2 1]]

newframe=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columnas)
print (newframe)
data level 1   h/a                        totals                       
data level 2 means       percentage        means       percentage      
data level 3     a  b  c          g  h  i      a  b  c          g  h  i
0                8  0  4          1  2  5      4  1  4          1  1  8
1                1  5  0          7  4  8      4  1  3          8  0  2
2                5  9  4          9  4  6      3  7  0          5  2  1
```

Comment: But if I do so, means and percentage will be parents of the same subset of column names. I used tuples because means have a subset of column names, for example, 'a','b','c', and percentage have a subset like 'd','e','f'. I will edit my post to clarify further. Thanks anyway